# asp.net: Location of username and password in WebForm and MVC

Tags: asp.net

If someone gives me WebForm/MVC website code using ASP.NET Membership (and he does not know the username/password), or I download it from the Internet without username/password information, how do I retrive username/password such that I can load it into VS2010, set up breakpoints, enter correct username/password, and run it to learn the code?

Comment: Depends on what membership provider is being used.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tw292whz.aspx

Answer (score 0):

That information is stored in a database. The web.config file will tell you where is the database located. Once you know this, you can query the table for user information but the passwords will be hashed; however, you can always create new users programmatically or even just run straight queries against the database to do whatever you want/need.